# Stop and restart a function from outside that function in python

Tags: python

I've been working on this for a few days now and I am pretty new to all this. I am using a raspberry pi 4 and the sensehat. What I want to do is have several different screens displayed on the LED matrix that I can switch between using the joystick. The problem is that some of these will be updating based on sensor data, so the functions to display them are not finishing. This makes stopping the running function and starting a new one difficult.

So far I have this:

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
from gpiozero import CPUTemperature
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

sense = SenseHat()


def main_display():
    w = (50, 50, 50)
    

    display = [
      w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w,
      w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w,
      w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w,
      w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w,
      w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w,
      w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w,
      w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w,
      w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w
      ]
    
    cpu_array = []
    while True:
#attempt at calibrating temp for cpu temp
        temp = sense.get_temperature()
        cpu = CPUTemperature()
        cpu_temp = cpu.temperature
        if len(cpu_array) < 100:
            cpu_array.append(cpu_temp)
        else:
            cpu_array.append(cpu_temp)
            cpu_array.remove(cpu_array[0])
        av_cpu_temp = sum(cpu_array) / len(cpu_array)
        temp_calibrated = temp - ((av_cpu_temp - temp) * 1.6)
        
        pres = sense.get_pressure()
        hum = sense.get_humidity()
        # temp column
        temp_list = [56, 57, 48, 49, 40, 41, 32, 33, 24, 25, 16, 17, 8, 9, 0, 1]
        temp_color = [(0, 0, 255), (20, 0, 235), (40, 0, 215), (70, 0, 185), (100, 0, 155), (120, 0, 135), (140, 0, 115), (160, 0, 95), (170, 0, 85), (180, 0, 75), (190, 0, 65), (200, 0, 55), (210, 0, 45), (220, 0, 35), (230, 0, 25), (255, 0, 0)]
        i = 0
        target_temp = 0
        while i < len(temp_list):
            if temp_calibrated >= target_temp:
                display[temp_list[i]] = temp_color[i]
            else:
                display[temp_list[i]] = w
            i += 1
            target_temp += 3
            
        # pres column    
        pres_list = [59, 60, 51, 52, 43, 44, 35, 36, 27, 28, 19, 20, 11, 12, 3, 4]
        pres_color = [(255,255,153), (255, 243, 157), (255,232,162), (255,209,172), (255, 197, 176), (255,185,181), (255,162,190), (255,139,199), (255,116,209), (255,93,218), (255, 81, 222), (255,70,227), (255,46,236), (255,23,246), (255, 11, 250), (255,0,255)]
        j = 0
        target_pres = 930
        while j < len(pres_list):
            if pres >= target_pres:
                display[pres_list[j]] = pres_color[j]
            else:
                display[pres_list[j]] = w
            j += 1
            target_pres += 10
            
        #hum column
        hum_list = [62, 63, 54, 55, 46, 47, 38, 39, 30, 31, 22, 23, 14, 15, 6, 7]
        hum_color = [(0,255,0), (0, 243, 11), (0,232,23), (0,209,46), (0,185,70), (0,162,93), (0, 150, 104), (0,139,116), (0,116,139), (0,93,162), (0, 81, 173), (0,70,185), (0,46,209), (0,23,232), (0, 11, 244), (0,0,255)]
        k = 0
        target_hum = 0
        while k < len(hum_list):
            if hum >= target_hum:
                display[hum_list[k]] = hum_color[k]
            else:
                display[hum_list[k]] = w
            k += 1
            target_hum += 6.25
            
        sense.set_pixels(display)
        time.sleep(1)
        
        
p = Process(target=main_display)
p.start()
while True:
    for event in sense.stick.get_events():

        if event.action == "pressed":
            if event.direction == "up":
                p.start()
            elif event.direction == "down":
                p.terminate()
                sense.clear()
```

It almost works, but when I try to restart the the main_display function after terminating it, I get an error that a function can only be started once.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into generators and yield keyword.

Essentially what it allows you to put some sort of a breakpoint and exit from functions temporarily. I believe what you are trying to do could be solved using generators

Comment: I just gave generators a quick try and I might be implementing it wrong but I ran in to a couple problems. One is that the breakpoint given by the yield keyword always stops the function until called again, rather than continuing the function and then stopping it when an action is performed. The other is that I can’t seem to use the output of the generator function in the sense_hat .set_pixels() method because it checks for a len(). Generators seem like the way to go, I just can’t figure out how to implement them here.